# Windows 7 download speed slow through router

Tags: windows-7, speed

I am using Windows 7. When I plug in the Internet connection directly to windows 7, its download speed can get up to 60Mbps. However, when I connect Windows 7 through my Linksys Router, the download speed is only 9Mbps. If I use Linux to connect to the router, its speed can also go up to 60Mbps. The problem is definitely something in windows 7. I have changed the network adapter to 100Mbps Full Duplex. No use. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: How are you checking your connection speed? Are you referring to the connection speed or the actual transfer speed?

Answer (score -1):

I think this may be a viable solution:

http://www.winbeta.org/news/how-force-windows-8-use-100-your-bandwidth-and-prevent-bandwidth-limiting

I know default Windows will limit the data rate on individual files. I do hope this may help or at least give you something to try.

Even though the link is for Windows 8, I would think that it could still apply for Windows 7.

Comment: This group policy setting does not exist in windows 7. If you are unsure, please research first before posting, or post as a comment instead. Secondly, I use windows 7 and I can download with the full 150 Mbit without any setting.

Comment: Windows DOES limit the transfer rate per individual file though.